# error on homepage: Notice: Undefined variable: percentage

Tags: undefined-variable

We are having an error on the [homepage](http://www.thehomewarescompany.com)  by

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: percentage  in /var/www/vhosts/live/kg-electronics/htdocs/app/design/
 frontend/kg/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml on line 277
```

Comment: post the code of `price.html` by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

You need to define the variable before attempting to use it. It seems that somewhere in your price.phtml file you have made a modification to display a `$percentage` variable and the logic in price.phtml is executing in such a way that it is not initialized before you attempt to use it.

There are two ways to initialize a variable.

1. Declare it in your code with a default value:

   $percentage = 0;
2. Declare it in a class as a member variable (it doesn't apply to your current issue).

To resolve this you need to declare it somewhere near the top of price.phtml as shown in example 1 above.

### However

There may be a **larger issue** here. Magento **should not display notices** by default. In this case you may have deployed a development version of index.php or you have an environment variable set in your vhost configuration. Please review to make sure that these have been addressed.

Comment: The variable Phil is referring to its MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE.